# What is the connection between the Mersenne-Twister and Linear Congruential Generator?

Tags: pseudo-random-generators

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C82JyCmtKWg) claims that the Mersenne-Twister is based on the Linear Congruential Generator. The math in the Mersenne-Twister original paper is a bit too much for me. I have not seen that claim explicitly made in the wikipedia article for Mersenne-Twister or in some of the other sources I consulted. Is the Mersenne-Twister based on the Linear Congruential Generator? High level, how so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not.

MT is based on a twisted generalized feedback shift register. It is defined on vector spaces over finite fields, specifically [$GF(2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2)).

The LCG is based on integer arithmetic over the integers modulo $n,$ say $\mathbb{Z}_n.$

The two algebraic structures are quite different so this statement is false.